# Is epoll a bad idea for udp client?

Tags: c++, udp, epoll

I have created a linux server using epoll. And I realized that the clients will use udp packets...

I just erased the "listen" part from my code and it seems like working. But I was wondering any hidden issues or problems I might face.

Also, is this a bad idea using epoll for server if clients are sending udp packets?

Comment: My projects uses epoll with a mixture of UDP, TCP, timers, and other events and I've seen no particular problems relating to the UDP bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the respective thread does not need to do anything else but receive UDP packets, you can as well just block on `recvfrom`, this will be the exact same effect with one less syscall and less code complexity.

On the other hand, if you need to do other things periodically or with some timely constraints that should not depend on whether packets arrive on the wire, it's better to use epoll anyway, even if it seems overkill.
The big advantage of epoll is that besides being reasonably efficient, it is comfortable and extensible (you can plug in a signalfd, timerfd or eventfd and many other things).